# Controller not getting ID from model, returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my view, I have a table of records (cars) and a 'Edit' button which goes to my Edit actionresult method in my controller.

I then have this code in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? ID, Search sobj)
    {
        //CarRepository car = new CarRepository();
        sobj.carrepos = new CarRepository();

        if (ID.HasValue)
        {
            sobj.carrepos.populateStatusList();
            sobj.carrepos.getCarToUpdate(ID);

            //sobj.carrepos.ID = ID;

            return View("Edit", sobj);
        }
        else
        {
            sobj.carrepos.populateStatusList();
            return View("Edit", sobj);
        }           
    }
```

In my search model, I have an instance of the CarRepository class, that I can access it's methods/data. In this question, ID that is null, is in CarRepository class.

This is what it looks like (i've removed alot of code that doesnt need to be seen:

```
    public class Search
{

    public CarRepository carrepos { get; set; }

    public Search() {}

}
```

When ID.HasValue (passed in when I click 'Edit' for a record) is for e.g. 49, sobj.carrepos.getCarToUpdate(ID); is run and gets the car details for the specified ID.

This is the code in my CarRepository class:

```
public void getCarToUpdate(int? ID)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                dbConn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

                cmd.Connection = dbConn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, carMake, carModel, engine, deleteStatus FROM myprojectdb WHERE ID = ?ID";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = ID;
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ID = (int)reader[0];
                        carMake = (string)reader[1];
                        carModel = (string)reader[2];
                        Engine = (string)reader[3];
                        deleteStatus = (string)reader[4];
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                dbConn.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        dbConn.Close();

    }
```

When I put a break point at this location:

```
return View("Edit", sobj);
```

and look at the properties for sobj, ID = null

It's only when I add the following code:

```
sobj.carrepos.ID = ID;
```

It starts working again, which yes, I see why but not sure why it loses the ID value, the SQL query is working perfectly when fetching all data.

Here is how I use it in view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.carrepos.ID)
```

Rest of the code is boilerplate code.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: I've read this question three times.  It isn't clear what you're asking or what your issue is.

Comment: sobj.carrepos.id = getCarToUpdate(ID);

Comment: Apologies, I'll amend to make it clearer. Dreamweaver, thanks for your answer, I already have a fix (mentioned in the code) but feel as though i don't need the extra line of code (not trying to be difficult, unless you can explain otherwise

Comment: The ID that is null, is this the one from `carrepos.ID`? It's not too clear. Please clarify further

Comment: Hopefully makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you are testing for is not part of the object. `carrepos.ID` is null because you are creating the object in your first executable line `sobj.carrepos = new CarRepository();`. At this point, all its properties are null.

You can create it this way `sobj.carrepos = new CarRepository { ID = ID};` and that should fix it

**Update**

After looking at your updated question, I would say the problem is that your parameter `ID` is shadowing your property `ID` and thus the property never gets set. You can solve it in one of 2 ways

```
// Fully qualify your property
this.ID = (int)reader[0];
```

Or redefine the argument like so

```
public void getCarToUpdate(int? id)
{
    try
    {
        if (dbConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            cmd.Connection = dbConn;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, carMake, carModel, engine, deleteStatus FROM myprojectdb WHERE ID = ?ID";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("?ID", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = id;
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ID = (int)reader[0];
                    carMake = (string)reader[1];
                    carModel = (string)reader[2];
                    Engine = (string)reader[3];
                    deleteStatus = (string)reader[4];
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            dbConn.Close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    dbConn.Close();

}
```

Note that I have changed the parameter to the small `id` and that way the property can be visible from within the method.

Comment: When this line of code is run:    sobj.carrepos.getCarToUpdate(ID); ID is passed to CarRepository and the SQL returns the ID, anyway

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the updated question.

Comment: Thanks, Fabulous. I researched into your answer and "ID is shadowing your property ID" was what was happening here. :)))